# For each fails when there is only one cell selected

Tags: vba, excel

I am selecting a range into variant in VBA

```
Dim source as variant
source = Range("A4:A" & rowcount)
```

and then I am having a for each

```
For Each element in source 
.....
.....
```

This works when there are 2-3 values selected, but when rowcount is 4,`Range("A4:A" & rowcount)` will select only a cell and for each is not working

How can I make it work even when only one value is there

I tried

```
If (rowcount=4) Then
    redim preserve source(1)
    source(1,1) = source
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it 2 dimensional

```
Dim var As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim thing As Variant
Set rng = Range("a1")
If rng.CountLarge = 1 Then
    ReDim var(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    var(1, 1) = rng.Value2
Else
    var = rng.Value2
End If
For Each thing In var
    MsgBox thing
Next thing
```

Comment: thanks Williams
can i delete the last element in variant? because now i have selected a empty last row

Comment: If you want to test for empty cells use Isempty(var)

Comment: i have to check that in many places since there are many arrays like this :( is there a way i can delete only the last element alone

Comment: When you assign a variant to more than a single cell you get a 2 dimensional array constructed on a 1-based index (e.g. lbound(source, 1) = 1). If you assign a single cell value you do not get an array at all. I think the best way to handle this would be two methods decided upon an `If Range("A4:A" & rowcount).cells.count > 1`. see [Variant Data Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx).

Comment: @Jeeped: isn't that exactly what I posted?

Comment: Sorry @CharlesWilliams - I was hoping to give credence to your statements and recommend a method but I neglected to address the comment to Harish jayakumar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check if this works for you:

Where, ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) refers to Sheet1 of your workbook.

```
Sub try()
Dim source As Range
RowCount = 4
Set source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A4:A" & RowCount)

For Each element In source
MsgBox "hi"

Next

End Sub
```