# delete element from variant in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variant which has list of source

```
Dim source as variant
source = Range("A4:A" & rowcount)
```

Sometimes the `rowcount` is also 4 so in that case I am reassigning the source to

```
source = Range("A4:A5")
```

Now I want to delete the last row `source(2)/source(2,1)`

How can I delete it?

I tried `Erase source` which clears everything

I am processing the data in the source and populating few dict items
I have to make changes in many places if source is not an array since i have used for each in many places

How can I just have the first element alone or remove the last element?

Comment: `source` should be declared as `Range`, unless... What are you tryiung to achieve? Why do you want to delete last row? Please improve your question.

Comment: i have to make changes in many places if i change the type of the source
So i am trying to get a quick fix which will delete the last element alone

Comment: How is this related to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231842/for-each-fails-when-there-is-only-one-cell-selected)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `ReDim Preserve` because even for just one cell your variant set with Range will be in 2D.

Use `.Value` or `.Value2` to get a proper array and a buffer variable to erase and transfer back in source your data :

```
Dim source as variant, A()
Redim A(0)

If rowcount<>4 Then
    source = Range("A4:A" & rowcount).Value
Else
    source = Range("A4:A5").Value
    A(0)=source(1,1)
    Redim source(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    source(1,1)=A(0)
End if
```

Comment: i want to have it as source(1,1)  = A(0) is that possible